# Form for Devise action controller duplicating data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, elm

I'm using `devise-4.4.1` on `rails-5.1.4` with elm `0.18` to build a signup form to post data to the classic `/users.json` action which is defined here:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

The Elm form is quite common as well, I'm using [etaque/elm-form](https://github.com/etaque/elm-form) and serializing into JSON:

```
case formMsg of
  Form.Submit ->
    case user_ of
      Just user_ ->
        let 
          request = Http.post "/users.json" (Http.jsonBody (user userDecode
        in
          ( model , Http.send PostUser request )
      Nothing ->
        ({ model | form = form_ }, Cmd.none)
```

This works well, and this is the Json I'm receiving as per browser "Copy POST data"

```
{
  "user": {
    "type":"designer",
    "role":"designer",
    "first_name":"dsfdsfsd",
    "last_name":"dsdsfds",
    "email":"dfsddfs@kdsfjfgkd",
    "password":"fdsfdfsdfds"
  }
}
```

But unfortunately this is what `params.inspect` tells me from inside the Devise Registration controller:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
11:02:06 web.1     |   Parameters: {"user"=>{"type"=>"designer", "role"=>"designer", "first_name"=>"sdadas", "last_name"=>"asdasda", "email"=>"sadasad@fsdfd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"type"=>"designer", "role"=>"designer", "first_name"=>"sdadas", "last_name"=>"asdasda", "email"=>"sadasad@fsdfd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
```

As you can see the data looks like it's duplicated, I have a `user` hash and a `registration[user]` hash.

Here is the controller code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    puts params.inspect
    super
  end

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:type, :role, :first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

My question is: what is Devise doing and why? Am I missing something here? It looks like Elm is working as it's supposed to work, the create action is receiving the right data. Does anybody have a clue?